# Add-ons preferences won't show up

Tags: add-on, customization

as shown in the screenshot below, sins I installed some add-ons I opened blender and I found that the add-ons preferences won't show up, I tried to reset preferences to factory, and I  reboot my PC and I even reinstalled it and the issue remains unsolved.

what can cause this problem? and what solutions you propose?
thank you

blender version 2.90.1

[image]

Comment: Check for error messages on the console (*Windows > Toggle System Console*).

Comment: That's really weird, it shouldn't be happening.  It's probably a bug.  Or maybe your file is corrupted?  idk

Comment: Half way thru same comment as @RobertGützkow when browser crashed. Also consider starting from console, User installed  addons are installed to ./scripts/addons of  USER folder https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#blender-s-directory-layout   which is not touched by installer

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the user installed addons in this direcrtory

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\
```

which is not touched by the installer and yeah it worked

problem solved thanks to @batFINGER

Comment: Good one. Remember a question where someone mistakenly unzipped an addon into addons folder. The wrongly unzipped addon had a `types` module which was the cause of the same issue.

Comment: should I delete this question because it"s duplicated.?